# Integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \arctan \left(2\tan^2 x\right) \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

The following integral may seem easy to evaluate ...

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan \left(2 \tan^2 x\right) \mathrm{d}x = \pi \arctan \left( \frac{1}{2} \right).
> $$

Could you prove it?

Comment: Have you tried the variable $u=2.tan^2(x)$ ?

Comment: Are you challenging people to prove it? If so, do you have your own solution? You can always post it using >! before to hide it.

Comment: @user37238 Thanks! I did not know this functionality! Where can I have more explanations about it? Yes, you have to see this integral as a small challenge.

Comment: Have you tried compuer algebra systems?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal I didn't test it, but you are right, Mathematica finds it! >$\,\frac{\pi}{2}  \text{ArcTan}\left[\frac{4}{3}\right]$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Actually, I haven't used this functionality yet. Look for examples (typing spoiler may help).

Comment: @OlivierOloa: I found this answer $ \pi/8 \, \left( \pi +4\,\arctan \left( 1/7 \right)  \right). $ Your first answer $\pi\arctan(1/2)$ is correct too.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal Thank you! I also have solution for $\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan \left(t \tan^2 x\right) \mathrm{d}x $, but it is a bit long ...

Comment: @OlivierOloa: The three different forms of answers are equivalent. By the way what form of a solution you got?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey You edited my post, but please, don't change the initial answer $\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \arctan \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)\right) $, which is correct and simpler. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, it might help in the future to indicate such problems status as 'challenges'. I recognized it as such but it's not obvious from the question statement.

Comment: @Semiclassical I do agree with you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is different from that you gave. Let
$$ I(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan(a\tan^2x)dx. $$
Than $I(0)=0$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(a)&=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan^2x}{1+a^2\tan^4x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)(1+a^2u^4)}du\\
&=&\frac{1}{1+a^2}\int_0^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{1+u^2}+\frac{1+a^2u^2}{1+a^2u^4}\right)du\\
&=&\frac{1}{1+a^2}\left(-\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+u^2}du+\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+a^2u^4}du+\int_0^\infty\frac{a^2u^2}{1+a^2u^4}\right)du\\
&=&\frac{1}{1+a^2}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{a}\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I=\int_0^2I'(a)da=\pi\arctan(1+\sqrt{2a})\Big]_0^2=-\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\pi\arctan 3=\frac{\pi}{2}\arctan\frac{4}{3}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Our $I$ are not the same. What is your final result for your $I$?

Comment: why you can take the differentiation inside the integral? Can you justify it?

Comment: @OlivierOloa,I fixed the problem.

Comment: @QinfengLi, I just revised the answer. I made a mistake before.

Comment: @xpaul Please, I don't understand your antepenultimate equality.

Comment: I'm sorry but and I still don't understand your first step. I remember there are some conditions on taking the differentiation (limit) inside an integral, for example, dominated convergence theorem, something like that.

Comment: @QinfengLi, you can check that the condition for taking the differentiation (limit) inside an integral holds. Of course, you can use the DCT.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I didn't realize the difference quotient of $arctan$ function is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a result avoiding differentiation with respect to a parameter.

> Set$$ I(\alpha):= \int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan \left(\frac{2\alpha \:\sin^2 x}{\alpha^2-1+\cos^2 x}\right)\: \mathrm{d}x, \quad \alpha>0. $$ 
>   Then
>   $$  I(\alpha)= \pi \arctan \left(\frac{1}{2\alpha}\right) \quad ({\star})
> $$

With $ \alpha:=1$, we get
$$
\int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan \left(2 \tan^2 x\right) \mathrm{d}x = \pi \arctan \left( \frac{1}{2} \right).
$$
To obtain $({\star})$ use the standard evaluation extended to complex numbers

> $$
> \int_{0}^{\Large\frac{\pi}{2}} \log \left(1+ t \sin^2 x\right) \mathrm{d}x = \pi \log \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1+t}}{2} \right)
> $$

and observe that 
$$
 \arctan (z) = \frac{i}{2}  \left(\log (1-i z)-\log (1+i z)\right), \quad\Re z \neq 0.
$$

Comment: I don't understand your last two equalities. Could you please show some more details? Cause at first glance I don't think the last two equalities are easier to be obtained than the original question.